# How to show the http.agent opening and closing sockets in the terminal based on the timeout set

Tags: node.js

Using a proxy server in Node.js to send in request to httpbin.org. Looked up documentation on http.Agent and how it handles connection pooling and wanted to use loadtest to simulate concurrent requests and show in the terminal the sockets opening and closing based on the agent configuration; maxSockets, maxFreeSockets keepAlive, timeout, etc.

I tried just printing the agent every single time a request is received but wanted a cleaner way to see it rather then getting a huge text of the agents configuration

```
var fs = require('fs'),
    https = require('https'),
    httpProxy = require('http-proxy'),
    http = require('http')

// Custom Agent
var proxyAgent = new http.Agent({ keepAlive: true, maxSockets: 3, keepAliveMsecs: 30000, timeout: 30000 });

// Create your proxy server 
var proxy = httpProxy.createProxyServer({agent: proxyAgent});

// Create your target server
var server = http.createServer(function(req, res) {
    proxy.web(req, res, { target: 'http://httpbin.org/' });
  });

server.listen(8080);
console.log("running on 8080")

proxy.on('proxyRes', function (res) {
  console.log('Opened socket: ' + res.socket.localPort);
  //console.log(proxyAgent)
});
```